# How to prevent time change on refresh after displaying once?

Tags: javascript, html

How to prevent time change on refresh after displaying once?
Trying to achieve the time to be saved once upon generating each html.

```js
const d = new Date();
let text = d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div>
    <b>Time Generated: </b><span style="padding-right:410px" id='time'</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can store it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You'd have to persist the data somewhere.  Local storage, session storage, a cookie, a server, etc.  Any time the page loads it executes the code that's on that page.  That code, currently, creates a new `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the date on the [Session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

i choose  the first one for this example, but you need to know that **Session storage only persists for as long as the current browsing session and is cleared as soon as the browser is closed**, if ou want a long term storage you need to use Local Storage.

First check if is the first time on the page:

```
sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;    
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('date')) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('date', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}
```

And then get the date:

```
text = sessionStorage.getItem('date');
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = text;
```

I hope it helps you, have a nice day!

Comment: Edit queue is full but I'd suggest adding into your answer that SessionStorage only persists for as long as the current browsing session and is cleared as soon as the browser is closed. If OP needs long term storage then localStorage is a more viable option. Also, please use [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) or some other code formatter to format the code in your answer.

Comment: Done!, thanks for the advice, im still a new user here and i make a lot of mistakes when i answer a question ^^'